# JS script working only on one html card instead of all

Tags: javascript, html, web

So this Script changes the currency and symbol if I selected the currency from a select tag in html, but the problem is that it changes the currency and symbol only for the first card but the others not. Is there a way to change them all at the same time without doing a script for every card?
the select works as follows: If I chose LBP and the currency was USD then the number would be multiplied by 8500 and if chose USD with the currency being in LBP then it would be divided by 8500, while if I chose the same currency that is chosen then nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
        <img class="imgcar" src="cars/402088-2020-land-rover-range-rover-velar.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:16em">
        <div class="container">
          <h4><b>Range Rover Velar</b><br><b>4 Doors</b><br><b> 5 Passengers</b> </h4>
          <div><p id="price">100</p><p id="symbol">$</p><p id="duration">/24hrs</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="imgcar" src="cars/2020-BMW-M8-Competition-Convertible-02-e1570483239877.jpg" alt="Avatar"
          style="width: 16em;">
        <div class="container">
          <h4><b>BMW M8</b><br><b>2 Doors</b><br><b> 2 Passengers</b></h4>
          <p id="price">150</p><p id="symbol">$</p><p id="duration">/24HRS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JS:

```
function report(currencyy) {
var price = document.getElementById("price");
var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol");

if (currencyy == "lbp") {
  if (symbol.textContent == "$") {
    symbol.textContent = "lbp";
    var text = price.textContent;
    var number = parseInt(text) * 7500;
    price.textContent = number;
  }
 }
 if (currencyy == "usd") {
  if (symbol.textContent == "lbp") {
    symbol.textContent = "$";
    var text = price.textContent;
    var number = parseInt(text) / 7500;
    price.textContent = number;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and iterate over the cards nodes:

```js
const currencies = { //--> store the currency data
  lbp: {
    symb: "lbp",
    fn: value => Number(value) * 7500
  },
  usd: {
    symb: "$",
    fn: value => Number(value) / 7500
  }
};

function report(currencyy) {
  var cardNodes = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  Array.from(cardNodes).forEach(card => { // --> update the card node data
    const symbNode = card.querySelector("#symbol");
    const priceNode = card.querySelector("#price");
    const { symb, fn } = currencies[currencyy];
    if (symbNode.textContent === symb) return;
    symbNode.textContent = symb;
    priceNode.textContent = fn(priceNode.textContent);
  });

  
}

report("usd");
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<div class="card">
    <img class="imgcar" src="cars/402088-2020-land-rover-range-rover-velar.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:16em">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>Range Rover Velar</b><br><b>4 Doors</b><br><b> 5 Passengers</b> </h4>
        <div>
            <p id="price">100</p>
            <p id="symbol">$</p>
            <p id="duration">/24hrs</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
    <img class="imgcar" src="cars/2020-BMW-M8-Competition-Convertible-02-e1570483239877.jpg" alt="Avatar"
          style="width: 16em;">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>BMW M8</b><br><b>2 Doors</b><br><b> 2 Passengers</b></h4>
        <p id="price">150</p>
        <p id="symbol">$</p>
        <p id="duration">/24HRS</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a very bad idea to duplicate an ID...
[Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) return only one `DOM element`, so my advice is that you use classes, and then, use [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassname) or:

```
node.querySelectorAll('.yourClassName').forEach(element => {
  // Your code
})
```

Comment: I used document.getElementByClassName() but it stopped working ,it used to change the currency of the first card, now not. ( I edited he html to class instead of id)

Comment: Do you mean document.getElementsByClassName() ? document.getElementByClassName() doesn't exist, maybe that's why it didn't work.

Comment: you mentioned above to use document.getElementsByClassName() instead if the ID one